# Local variable inside function is accessed outside the function after the function has executed. How does this happen?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

This code generates a sentence by randomly fitting together words from 3 string arrays.

```js
var arrAimals = ["Dog", "Rat", "Cat"];
var arrNames = ["Amy", "George", "Mary"];
var arrAction = ["Hides", "Finds", "steals"];
var num = 0;
var hero = generateHero();

var stories = [];

var createStory = function(){
    var animal = generateAnimal();
    stories.push(function(){
        var action = generateAction();
        console.log(hero + " " + action + " " + animal);
    });
}
function generateHero(){
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // random number between 0 - 2
    var hero  = arrNames[num];
    return hero;
}
function generateAnimal(){
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // random number between 0 - 2
    var animal = arrAimals[num];
    return animal;
}
function generateAction(){
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // random number between 0 - 2
    var action = arrAction[num];
    return action;
}

createStory();
stories[0]();
stories[0]();
stories[0]();
stories[0]();
stories[0]();
```

For example lets take this is the output for this time.

```
George steals Dog
George steals Dog
George Finds Dog
George steals Dog
George Hides Dog
```

hero is the same because it's a global variable.

action is different each time. This also I think I understand. stories[0] stores the reference to the callback function. So each time `stories[0]()` is called, the function is called a new so a different action would be generated each time.

However, the variable animal is also same each time (Dog).

What I don't understand is how the animal variable is accessed at all.
Local variable animal's scope is only inside createStory().

`stories[0]()` bypasses createStory() and directly executes the callback method.
So, how is the previous value of animal retained each time you call `stories[0]()` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the link that @Ryan has posted. That answers your question. These kind of questions are answered million times on SO, please use google to search around.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Ryan. I understood it now only.

Comment: It is called closures. You can watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71AtaJpJHw0 to get understand how it works, behind the scene. It is explained extremely good.